# SSH config to restore user ssh access?

Tags: ssh, google-compute-engine, openssh

I have been locked out of ssh. I'm on the Google Cloud, so I can move the hd over and change the ssh config files, but after a few attempts, I cannot login still. The problem began shortly after I changed the password to the primary account, but since SSH was not using password authentication, I am surprised that affected SSH. I tried turning password authentication on, generating new keys, have Google's platform generate new keys, etc, but nothing has allowed me to log in.

I keep getting this error, regardless of key combo or whether or not password authentication is on.
Permission denied (publickey).

I have a slightly older backup (a couple hours, before the issue), and it's telling me too many authentication failures for any user (regarless of user@domain.com).

I was wondering if there are any config setting I can set to be able to log back in.

Comment: have you resolved your issue? If not, how are you trying to connect? Are you using `ssh` directly? Or are you using `gcloud compute ssh`? Have you tried any of the suggestions in the answers below?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this belongs stackoverflow or serverfault but..

Try adding `-vv` to your ssh command. It shows a lot more debugging info

For example:

```
ssh -vv username@host
```

See if that gets you any hints! It could be a number of things, it searching for private key in the wrong place, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The issue could be ssh keys saved in your local computer. Can you move the ssh keys from .ssh/ to a different directory in your local computer and see if that resolves the issue.

Or can you enable password authentication for your ssh and use -o flag with ssh command which forces non-key authentication to confirm if the issue was with the key: ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no username@

You also set MaxAuthTries to higher number in your sshd_config.